# How to insert the contents of one file to an exact place in another file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have two files. The first one contains html code:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('<textarea rows="3"></textarea>', '<textarea rows="3"> inserthere </textarea>');
```

The second file looks like this:

```
A B C D E F G
```

I need to put the contents of the second file into the html code where `inserthere` is. So, output I want:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('<textarea rows="3"></textarea>', '<textarea rows="3"> A B C D E F G </textarea>');
```

or

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('<textarea rows="3"></textarea>', '<textarea rows="3"> A B C D E F Ginserthere </textarea>');
```

What I tried:

```
sed  -e '/inserthere/r file2' -e 'x;$G' file1 > file3 

sed -n -i -e '/inserthere/r file2' -e 1x -e '2,${x;p}' -e '${x;p}' file1  

f2="$(<file2)"
awk -vf2="$f2" '/inserthere/{print f2;print;next}1' file1
```

After these commands, the contents of second file were put at the end of the first file instead of the place I wanted.

Is there any other way to achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can get the `r` command in `sed` to replace text in the middle of a line. You can use `sed s` to replace `inserthere` with the contents of `file2` in an inelegant way:

```
sed "s/inserthere/$(cat file2)/" file1 > file3
```

**Explanation**:

- `s` replace: `/old/new/`
- `$(cat file2)` pass the output of `cat file2` to `sed s` (command substitution)
- use double quotes to allow `$` expansion

**file3**:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('<textarea rows="3"></textarea>', '<textarea rows="3"> A B C D E F G </textarea>');
```

Comment: ^_^ always a pleasure @PKM

Comment: This only works for files without characters having special meaning to sed.  The sample file is fine.